# Вопрос по OOП и циклам в php.

Tags: ооп, циклы

Есть объект:

```
$result -> $cans -> $company -> $info
```

В $info может что-то быть или не быть вовсе.
Как узнать, если хоть одна из $info содержит данные, то вывести на экран их все?
Не знаю, как использовать циклы в ООП.

Comment: Вы не поверите, но циклы работают точно также, как и с ООП, так и без ООП.

Comment: а при чем тут ООП?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

так же, как и в любой другой парадигме программирования

```
foreach ($result->cans as $can) {
    foreach($can->company as $company) { // эй, а тут точно массив?
        if(isset($company->info)) {
            print_r($company->info);
        }
    }
}
```

если же я неправильно понял, и у вас массив объектов типа $result, а в цепочке нет массивов, только объекты как свойства других объектов:

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    if (isset($result->cans->company->info)) {
        print_r($result->cans->company->info);
    }
}
```